# Creating vertices in multiple mxWindows

Tags: mxgraph

I want to create multiple mxWindows in the mxGraph javascript library.
All vertices I create seem to appear in the last mxWindow I created, even if I create the vertices before the second mxWindow is created.

Which parent should I use? System does not accept mxWindow objects as parent.
Using graph.getDefaultParent does not help, as it always seem to return the same parent that is associated with the most recent mxWindow.

How can I specify a separate parent for each mxWindow?

Any example code creating a vertex in one mxWindow and another vertex in another mxWindow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I need to create a second top element

```
<div id="graphContainer1"
  style "overflow:auto;position:abolute;width:100%;height:100%;..."
</div>

<div id="graphContainer2"
  style "overflow:auto;position:abolute;width:100%;height:100%;..."
</div>
```

and create a separate graph object for each container.

```
container2 = document.getElementById('graphContainer2');
graph2 = new mxGraph(container2);
..
window2 = new mxWindow('second window', container2, x, y, w, h, true, true);
..
```